# Issue with Stack Overflow Voting / Reputation System

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

**Scenario 1:**

- A new user posts a question
- The question is downvoted -4
- The user now has 1 reputation
- The question is upvoted +1
- The question now has -3 votes
- The user now has 11 reputation

**Scenario 2:**

- A new user posts a question
- The question is upvoted +1
- The user now has 11 reputation
- The question is downvoted -4
- The question now has -3 votes
- The user now has 3 reputation

Comment: It's not a bug. It's well known and intented that rep can't go under 1, and that for the first couple of posts, you rep may be a bit inaccurately reflected by your score due to that.

Comment: I understand. I'm not suggesting the reputation should go into negative, I'm just saying that there's an inconsistency between the users reputation even though they both have the exact same stats.

Comment: "It's well known" -- can you support that claim with a link?

Comment: Why continue to downvote? The question is valid and has been updated

Comment: Cause it's possible poorly researched? Doing "StackOverflow rep under 1" gives me the correct link that Makoto points to. Can't say this is well-researched or useful

Comment: I would call it inconsistent when a downvote which happened in the past is then considered when someone upvotes later. That's the same when reaching the reputation threshold. You also don't keep on 200 when you surpassed it already and someone downvotes a post of you.

Comment: Well, I discovered the issue myself recently.. Why would I search "StackOverflow rep under 1" when that's not even a thing that exists? I searched "StackOverflow reputation bug" but anyways, it's irrelevant.. I can't delete the question either as someone has answered

Comment: @AK47 on meta like on main stack, you are expected to do research. A meta post somewhere mentions "an insane amount of research. Then research some more". I would suggest not limiting yourself to only one google search before posting a question, or you'll hit walls like here.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest I figured I wasn't the first person to discover this issue, but I thought I'd just submit it as a bug anyways to bring it to the attention of the site regardless of whether it was already flagged. I forgot this was a Stackoverflow Site -- I treated the issue as I would when submitting a bug on any site -- send it to the team and let them decide what to do. I wasn't expecting downvotes for a valid inconsistency, but that's fine -- I'll know for the future

Comment: That's how reputation works here.

Comment: @AK47 makes sense :) It does seem like you're new to meta, so it is definitely the proper first try to do (before I get called out: It's the *logical* first thing to try, even if it's not the correct one necessarily) :). But remember that meta is moderated by the community, it's not the company's help desk :). So that's why this type of research is expected. In the meantime, don't worry about rep, as Meta doesn't affect rep at least ^^

Comment: Voting on meta is also more often than not a count of how many people agree with your post

Comment: It's an advantage of being at 1 rep: you can't lose any more. It's not an issue, it's by design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a bug.

[Reputation cannot be lower than 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/175248), so any negative rep applied to someone with 1 rep will not count against their visible reputation.